# JQuery animated banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I previously asked a question about how to create a banner like the one shown [here](http://osc4.template-help.com/drupal_30779/) and I got a really good answer to start me off. I have been working on it since and I'm having a lot of problems getting the animation to slide back to it's original position.

 Here is my animation: http://jsfiddle.net/43nCF/ (don't click the green block first)

 **Issue:** After the first time you toggle a block, clicking another block will not move it to the left.

I also have some other minor issues which I would be grateful if someone helped me with.

- How do I get the width and the moving of the blocks to animate simultaneously like in the banner animation I am trying to replicate?

  How do I get the block to slide back to the original position instead of just kind of 'transporting' there?

I am only beginner at jQuery so any help would be amazing.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have a response.
In case this version is of any help to you:
http://jsfiddle.net/vCbcz/
Instead of altering the divs other than the one being affected, I wrapped them all in a #slider div and adjusted that one's left margin to push it to the left.

```
$('#slider').animate({
    marginLeft: '-' + ind * 105 + 'px'
});
```

and back

```
$('#slider').animate({
    marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it =) I really like yours but your left margin is a bit misaligned when the image is expanded.I have a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/43nCF/8/ but it doesn't seem to work with internet explorer when yours does. How can I fix the margins?

Comment: I switched the calculation to use index * 105 instead of 100. That should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/vCbcz/1/
Quick question: Why are you adjusting the size of your other DIVs and not just the one you want to expand?

Comment: Thanks for the help! And I looked into it and I really don't know ^^;. The person who wrote the starter code in my last question put that in probably because in his example the images didn't expand. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 2):

As for the positioning problem: you need to drop the `left` declaration in your second function.

Regarding making the animation act simultanous: animate both the `right` and the `width` property for each element, in *one call*:

```
function() {
    var position = $.data(this, 'position');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    //moves image back to original position

    $('#container div').each(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            right: "",
            width: 100

        });
    });
});
```

[Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/43nCF/6/)

Comment: ahh thanks. I think I specifically added that because just having the right wasn't working =/.Do you have any insight on how to get the animation to play simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ***much*** easier way altogether of doing this. By using [jQuery's scrollTo plugin](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js), this can be done in a mere few lines of code, without using indices, calculations, or anything of that nature.

**Live Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/WEzny/

Comment: +1 Oh in my previous question I asked if there was a plugin to achieve the effect but I was advised just to code it myself. Nevertheless I don't like how the right margin moves before the blocks are reset.

Comment: That is all tweaked by adjusting the times a bit. Have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/WEzny/ - and in all fairness, the scolling plugin is just for scrolling. I am using it to slide all of the `block` elements at once.

Comment: ahh I see. I'm not fond of how the sliding of the left and right side aren't in sync but this is a neat plugin. I'll keep this in mind for future projects. Thanks a lot!